# Index out of range.Must be non Negative

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // In database there are three columns: proid, proname, and unitprice.
        // I need this to retrieve in respective textbox when i double click
        // the value in datagrid view
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from tblproduct where proid = " +
            Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + "", con);
        // Something wrong near this select statement so getting error index was out of range.
        da.Fill(dt);
        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least give a sentence regarding your issue, not just paste code

Comment: try `Convert.ToInt32(...`

Comment: Have you used the debugger to look at the sql query? Is it correct, does the same query retuns something in ssms?

Comment: @Jonesy the heading is the sentence

Comment: no selected rows in the datagrid?

Comment: The heading is the heading, he should have some description in the actual question

Comment: in comment i have mentioned sir.Near sql adapter i m getting error index out of range.

Answer (score 5):

This can only occur on four different lines:

```
// either SelectedRows or Cells is zero length
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]

// either Rows is zero length or there are no columns returned
dt.Rows[0][0]

// either Rows is zero length or there is only 1 column returned
dt.Rows[0][1]

// either Rows is zero length or there are only 2 columns returned
dt.Rows[0][2]
```

The most likely lines?

```
// there are no SelectedRows
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]

// there are no Rows returned
dt.Rows[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If SqlDataAdapter is like the other adapters I've used, you need to establish a connection first, which from the code sample you gave us does not appear you're doing. You might need to try something like this:

```
SqlConnection connex = new SqlConnection();
connex.ConnnectionString = "connection string to data";

try
{
    //connect to the database
    connex.Open();
    //set the select command to be used for pulling in info
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = connex;
    //fill the dbData object with data from the database
    da.Fill(dt);
    //close database connection
    connex.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: I believe "con" in the connection in the SqlDataAdapter

Comment: i have declared connection string globally sir